# Fibonacci Sqequence program, cannot figure out how to use the for loop to display the sequence

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

// Fibonacci Sequence
public class FibonacciSeq{ 
    // main method
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException { 
        // buffered reader
        BufferedReader keyboardInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        for (int x = 0 ; x < 15 ; x = x++) {
            System.out.print (x);

        }
    }
}
```

and then the output is just 0000000000.. etc and does not stop , the goal is that it is supposed to output the Fibonacci sequence up to 15

Comment: It depends.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: its supposed to show the Fibonacci sequence up to 15

Comment: Do you need the user to input anything?  If not, you won't need the BufferedReader.  I recommend adding the eventual goal to your question post.

Comment: no I do not need the user to input anything and ok

Comment: Clarify your question (title) so they unlock it and I can post you some code that will work.  As mentioned in another comment, you aren't completing the Fibonacci equation so your loop will just do 0-14.

Comment: okay , I changed the title

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop, *`for (x = 0 ; x < 15 ; x = x++)`* does not increment `x` and it doesn't declare `x`. I think you wanted something like

```
for (int x = 0 ; x < 15 ; x++)
```

when you use [post-increment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators#Examples) the increase doesn't happen until the next line (it evaluates to the previous value, which you then stored).

Comment: Yes, the issue lies in your for loop. Your code, however, will still not output the Fibonacci sequence. It will only output numbers 0 to 14 in a single row.

Comment: but it doesn't even do that , it just outputs 0000 .etc and wont stop

Comment: @Bre1448 As I explained, `x = x++` will not do what you think it does. You can use `x++` **or** `x = x + 1` **or** `++x` **and** `x = ++x`. But it's a post-increment and the assignment overrides.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the syntax of a for loop looks like this:

```
for(/* call me when the loop starts running*/;
    /* check me at the start of each iteration */;
    /* call me at the end of each iteration */) {}
```

In your case, you were missing the `int` keyword. Also, the statement `x = x++;` should be just `x++`, if you are trying to print `0-14`.

Comment: Those should be semicolons, not commas.

Comment: I added the "int " but now it just shows zeros and wont stop , I think its a infinite loop , should   I use a different type of loop ? I am kind of confused on loops , thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Add your code change and output in the question.  We don't know what you did, exactly.